# Should I need to define two fields per foreign key in ASP.NET Core EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core

Suppose that I need to have two tables named `Wagons` and `WagonTypes`. Obviously enough, each row in the `Wagons` table should reference to the correspoding `WagonTypes` record via foreign key.

Am I doing this right?

```
public class Wagons
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public WagonTypes Type { get; set; }
}

public class WagonTypes
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Yeah, it works and all that but I don't unserstand why there's an additional field in the [docs](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html) then:

```
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
```

What's the point of having a `BlogId` field? Should I define it too?

Comment: Your structure looks good. It's explained in documentation. Post.Blog is a reference navigation property. You don't have to add it.

Comment: From [docs](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/shadow-properties.html#conventions): _By convention, shadow properties are only created when a relationship is discovered but no foreign key property is found in the dependent entity class_

Comment: As I see it there's a slight difference between your example and the example referenced: in the reference example the relationship is one blog to many posts (so it makes sense that a post can have a navigation property back to the blog); in your example the inverse is true, a Wagon can only be of one WagonType so it doesn't make sense that you'll have a WagonType entity and want to get back to its parent wagon (the one-to-many relationship is the other way).

Comment: One benefit of specifying the foreign key separately is it allows you to retrieve the value of the foreign key without loading the entire related entity. (This is of benefit if you are using lazy loading - e.g. `public virtual WagonTypes Type { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the foreign key, but it's recommended because it makes your life easier.

Imagine you want to edit some row in table Wagons (for example property Name). You have to get the object, edit Name, then load property Type and then call SaveChanges. If you didn't load Type, EF would think you want to edit that Type too.

If you had `public int TypeId{ get; set; }` in your Wagons class, you could just get that object, directly edit Name and call SaveChanges without any further loading.